# Datetime's timestamp function not matching expected UNIX time

Tags: python, python-3.x, posix, utc, python-datetime

The following

```
import datetime as dt

dt.datetime(2019, 7, 21).timestamp()
```

returns

> 1563663600.0
>   .

However, if I look on https://www.unixtimeconverter.io/list/2019/july, then I see that the expected Unix time for this date is 1563667200.

Why the discrepancy?

Comment: what's your local timezone? `1563667200` is the `UTC` timestamp.

Comment: I was looking for the UTC timestamp. I didn't specify any local timezone when running `.timestamp()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime` doesn't assume UTC by default, so you need to specify it.

```
dt.datetime(2019, 7, 21, tzinfo=dt.timezone.utc).timestamp()
```

> 1563667200

Comment: This behavior/solution is specifically documented for [the `timestamp` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) too: "Note: There is no method to obtain the POSIX timestamp directly from a naive `datetime` instance representing UTC time. If your application uses this convention and your system timezone is not set to UTC, you can obtain the POSIX timestamp by supplying `tzinfo=timezone.utc`" (followed by code sample)